# Sphinx doctest: conditional test skipping

Tags: python-sphinx

This question is basically the same as [Python doctest: skip a test conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708809/2748899), except I'm **not** asking about [Python's native `doctest` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) but about [Sphinx's `doctest` extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/doctest.html):

Is there any way to skip doctests "dynamically" depending on some condition, which could e.g. be evaluated in the [setup code](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/doctest.html#directive-testsetup) for the given reST file? The documentation doesn't mention anything of the sort, but maybe someone has a good workaround.

Comment: This feature might not be that hard to create and contribute in `sphinx.ext.doctest`. It already includes the [pyversion](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html#directive-doctest) option (e.g. `:pyversion: > 3.3`), and a conditional skip would work very similarly.

Comment: I opened Sphinx issue [#5273](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5273) and created a [patch](https://github.com/akaihola/sphinx/commit/10f01d5539110c2080b69aff90af6ca0d269f0df) with this feature for the upcoming Sphinx 1.8 version.

Comment: Incidentally, the time is exactly right for this feature. Before the current 1.8 development code base, evaluating conditions in the context set up in the `doctest_global_setup` configuration option would have been hard, since directives didn't have access to configuration.

Comment: @akaihola You could post a short snippet on how to use your feature as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.